# How can you build an absolute URL in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I would like to display an absolute url generated at run-time with a parameter. Not create a href to a page but display the URL using `th:text`. Any simple way to do this with Tymeleaf (without having to concatenate the URL pieces from #request object and without using some MVC utility class)?

**Attempt 1**

`<p th:text="@{/myServlet(myParam=${dynamicParameter})}" />` - only displays part of the URL leaving out the protocol, port and host name. I am getting `/myServlet?myParam=123`. The same behavior as for `th:href`, if you inspect the `<a>` you will see the same href - in that case the browser helps by inferring the protocol, port and so on

**Attempt 2**

`th:text="@{__${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}__}"` - produces a relative URI of the current page that doesn't include the protocol and so on

**Attempt 3**

`th:text="@{__${#httpServletRequest.requestURL}__}"` - produces this time an absolute URL of the current page containing the protocol, host and servlet context. The problem now is when I display this text from a different page, my URL is `...myApp/myOtherServlet` so I need to edit this string to replace `myOtherServlet` with the URI I want.

**Non Tymeleaf Attempt 1**

```
@Service("urlUtils")
public class UrlUtilsServiceImpl implements UrlUtilsService {
@Override
    public String getAbsoluteUrlTo(final String aPath, final String param, final String value){
        return ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                .fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path(aPath)
                .queryParam(param, value)
                .build().toString();
    }
}
```

page.html:

```
th:text="${@urlUtils.getAbsoluteUrlTo('/myServlet', 'myParam', ${dynamicParameter})}"
```

The problem is the host name that can be aliased before it reaches my server (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482093/how-to-get-the-server-name-in-a-java-web-application)).
**Thymeleaf+JS Sollution**

Using some java script plus thymeleaf

```
<p id="myUrl" th:text="@{/myServlet(myParam=${dynamicParameter})}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myUrl= $("#myUrl");
        myUrl.text(window.location.origin + myUrl.text());
        });
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466130/spring-mvc-how-do-i-get-current-url-in-thymeleaf

Comment: @sujit - not a duplicate question, here I am asking about `th:text`. When using `th:href` like in the answer you suggest, the browser infers the rest of the url provided in the anchor href, the href attribute has a relative url in fact. Secondly, the URL I need to get is independent of the current URL when the page is displayed. Anyway, thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Ok. Glad that the link helped you get to `Attempt 3` ? Maybe calling `#request.getServletPath`  will help you identify the portion to cut from `#request.getRequestURL` so that u can derive your desired path string

Answer (score 4):

You can concatenate servlet request on the fly:

```
th:text="${#httpServletRequest.scheme}+'://'+${#httpServletRequest.serverName}+':'+${#httpServletRequest.serverPort}+@{/myServlet(myParam=${dynamicParameter})}"
```

Or for JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    GLOBAL.serverURI = '[[${#httpServletRequest.scheme}+'://'+${#httpServletRequest.serverName}+':'+${#httpServletRequest.serverPort}+@{/myServlet(myParam=${dynamicParameter})}]]';
</script>
```