# Client System Host Name is not captureing using request.getRemoteHost()

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

We are using `request.getRemoteHost()` in the jsp page to get the hostname of the client but it ll return only IP address of the  client system

Is any other way to get the client system host name from java-script,jsp,...

Comment: [Have a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591135/how-can-i-get-a-the-host-name-with-port-that-a-servlet-is-at)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get host name in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/get-host-name-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

If you server has enableLookups ( for example for Tomcat ) on false this getRemoteHost() will return only ip . Simplest solution would be to just change property and force resolving of ip to hostname.